# Where I can download Vertical Velocity data in the MERRA Reanalysis

Tags: reanalysis

I want to download Vertical Velocity data in the MERRA Reanalysis.
But I can not find it even I carefully went through the entire list of MERRA data.
This is the website I searched through: [enter link description here](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets?keywords=%22MERRA-2%22&page=1&source=Models%2FAnalyses%20MERRA-2)
Could you give me some hints?

Thank you so much.